# How to identify only change rows in datagrid which is bind ObservableCollection in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a data grid  which is bind the Observable Collection. First i load the data from the database. If i change one row and click on save button i should only update that particular row. if i add new rows, when i click save id should insert the rows to database. i don't have doubt to update and insert to database. But problem is how to identify the row changes.

```html
<DataGrid SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIntex}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsKeySet}" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Name="dgwTemplateDetails" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderTemplateList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrderTemplate}" IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="auto">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Change State" Visibility="Visible" Binding="{Binding ChangeState}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Srl No" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding SrlNo}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Act Code" Width="75" Binding="{Binding ActCode}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Act Name" Width="275" Binding="{Binding ActName}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="No. Of Days" Width="75" Binding="{Binding NoOfDays}"/>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Cutting" Width="75" Binding="{Binding IsCutSelected}" />
                      </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to identify this. However you can add another property in your class called *HasChanged*

```
public bool HasChanged { get; set; }
```

And in the setter code of any of your other properties, simply set the HasChanged property to true. For example:

```
private string _ActName; 
public string ActName 
{
   get
   {
      return _ActName;
   }
   set
   {
      _ActName = value;
      this.HasChanged = true;

      //INotifyPropertyChanged stuff if you are using it here.
   }
}
```

When you then save the changes to the database, you can simply select all of the records where the has changed property is set to true.

```
var hasChanged = OrderTemplateList.Where(x => x.HasChanged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement an `IsDirty` flag on your bound data objects. When you update the property values, set the `IsDirty` flag. In your Save `Command`, find all objects where the flag is set and update them and then reset the flag.